# Query tree structure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working with EntityFramework but can use other ways if need be

Here's the case: I have an SQL Server Database with a scheme similar to:

```
A           B           C           AhasB         AhasC
________    ________    ________    __________    ___________
AId         BId         CId         AId           AId
...         Btxt        Ctxt        BId           CId
            BParent     ...
            ...
```

Where `...` means other columns not important to the problem.

Tables `C` and `AhasC` are there to keep data during a lengthy process and are cleared on process completion, so i always start with both empty
Now, the process get's a lot of data (1000+ records) from online sources and stores it in `C`. After `C` is filled, I want to fill table `AhasC` based on the following:

```
INSERT INTO C (AId, CId) VALUES (
    SELECT A.AId, C.CId
    FROM A, B, C, AhasB
    WHERE A.AId = AhasB.AId AND B.BId = AhasB.BId AND
        C.CTxt IN (
            SELECT D.BTxt
            FROM B AS D
            WHERE D.BId = B.BId OR ??
        )
)
```

Before i explain what i need in `??` let me run through what i have here:

I want to insert into table AhasC the pair A.AId, C.CId, so that in all pairs, `C.CTxt` is the same as a `B.Btxt` that is connected to A in `AhasB`.

Moreover (and here enters the `??`) i also want it to match the `B.Btxt` of any parent of `B`.

Example:

```
A            B
_______      ____________________________________
AId = 1      BId = 1, BTxt = 'a', BParent = Null
AId = 2      BId = 2, BTxt = 'b', BParent = 1
AId = 3      Bid = 3, BTxt = 'c', BParent = 2
AId = 4      BId = 4, BTxt = 'x', BParent = Null

C                       AahsB
_____________________   _________
CId = 1, Ctxt = 'b'     AId = 1, BId = 3
CId = 2, CTxt = 'z'     AId = 3, BId = 4
```

This should result in:

```
AhasC
____________
AId = 1, CId = 1
```

So again, `AhasC` must connect `A` and C if `A` is connected to a `B` that either has `BTxt` equal to `CTxt`, or who's parent (or grand-parent and so on) has a BTxt that is the same as `CTxt`.

Hope i didn't overcomplicate my explaining here :p

**EDIT1:** as per @dotctor's coments, here's an image of my real shema (not that i think it will add much to the question)

[image: My Real Schema]

```
A = Contatos
B = Termos
C = ConcursosPublicos
AhasB = TermosContatos
AhasC = ConcursosContatos
A.AId = Contatos.Id
B.BId = Termos.Id
C.CId = ConcursosPublicos.Id
B.BTxt = Termos.Area
C.CTxt = ConcursosPublicos.Area
B.BParent = Termos.Pai
```

And here's my real code doing this work presently:

```
public static void Connect(ProgressBar progress)
{
    lock (Locker)
        using (var ctx = new ConcursosContainer())
        {
            int i = 0;
            IList<Contatos> contatos = ctx.Contatos.ToList();
            progress.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() =>
            {
                progress.Value = 0;
                progress.Maximum = contatos.Count;
            }));
            foreach (Contatos contato in contatos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(contato.Id);
                List<Termos> tree = GetTree(ctx, contato.Id).SelectMany(x => x.ToArray()).ToList();
                List<int> attr = ctx.ConcursosContatos.Where(x => x.ContatoId == contato.Id).Select(x => x.ConcursoId).ToList();
                IList<ConcursosPublicos> concursosPublicos = ctx.ConcursosPublicos.Where(x => !attr.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
                foreach (ConcursosPublicos concursosPublico in concursosPublicos)
                {
                    if (tree.Any(termo => (termo.Tipo == concursosPublico.TipoConc) && concursosPublico.Area.Trim().EndsWith(termo.Area)))
                    {
                        ctx.ConcursosContatos.Add(new ConcursosContatos
                        {
                            ContatoId = contato.Id,
                            ConcursoId = concursosPublico.Id
                        });
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (i == 9)
                    {
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                progress.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (progress.PerformStep));
            }
            if (i > 0)
                ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
}

private static IEnumerable<Stack<Termos>> GetTree(ConcursosContainer ctx, int id)
{
    var res = new List<Stack<Termos>>();
    IQueryable<Termos> terms = ctx.Termos.Where(x => ctx.TermosContatos.Any(y => (y.ContatoId == id) && (y.TermoId == x.Id)));
    foreach (Termos term in terms)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Termos>();
        if (term.Pai.HasValue)
            AddParent(ctx, stack, term);
        stack.Push(term);
        res.Add(stack);
    }
    return res;
}

private static void AddParent(ConcursosContainer ctx, Stack<Termos> stack, Termos term)
{
    Termos pai = ctx.Termos.First(x => x.Id == term.Pai.Value);
    if (pai.Pai.HasValue)
        AddParent(ctx, stack, pai);
    stack.Push(pai);
}
```

This code does the job but for 1000+ members of ConcursosPublicos and 7000+ members of Contatos (with contatos on way to grow in the future) it can take between 15 to 20 hours to complete. Since this a daily process i need a more efficient way to fill in ConcursosContatos

Comment: `AhasB` and `AhasC` are generated by entity framework? Can you post code for your POCOs?

Comment: They were created using EntityFramework Model-First - so poco's are auto generated - Is there anything specific you're wanting to see?

Comment: So you have entities named `AhasB` and `AhasC`?

Comment: I didn't use the same names in this short example as in my application but yes those entities exist in my application - and they're properly associated

Comment: @dotctor: I've added an image of my real schema to the question - does it help?

Answer (score 0):

You need some recursion to get the family tree on your B table. In SQL Server you can do this with a CTE:

```
;with chld as (
    select B.BId, B.BTxt, B.BParent 
    from dbo.B as B
    union all
    select chld.BId , b1.BTxt, b1.BParent  
    from dbo.B as B1
    inner join chld 
    on B1.BId = chld.BParent
)
select BId, BTxt from chld option(maxrecursion 32767)
```

The result set:

```
BId BTxt
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   x
3   b
3   a
2   a
```

If this isn't correct, no need to go any further. Otherwise, you can join this to the other tables as needed to populate your AhasC table.

Comment: Hi @JeffO - i did look into With and it looked promising but, where in your example do you compare BTxt to CTxt or us A at all? Also, how to use 'with ' when using entityframework?

Comment: One step at a time. Is this the result set you expect to get from all the child parent relationships in your B table? If it is, you can use this as a sub query to join to those tables for comparisons. I don't know how to do this in Entity Framework, but you could wrap this in a user-defined table function.

Comment: so, getting that operation's result separately. That's what i am doing now - but it makes it a very long process - 15 - 20 hours long (See my Edit in the question)

Comment: As for the result - that's not quite right - you'd need a where clause - but then i'd have to do all this once per BTxt - which am doing now taking 15 - 20 hours

Comment: Adding a proper where clause, a correct result would be, for 'Id 3', '3,2,1', for 'Id 2', '2,1', for 'Id 4', '4'